# Emissions issue with H-Bridge driving piezo transducers

Tags: h-bridge, emc, piezo

I have the following block in a PCB design:

[image: H-Bridge Block]

This drives a ~ 5W piezo transducer at 113KHz. The functionality of the system is great, nothing heats up at all. The issue is when I did a quick pre-compliance conducted emissions test using a DC LISN:
[image: H-Bridge with load]

If I remove the piezo, the emissions improve, but still are pretty terrible:
[image: H-Bridge with no load]

I have tried using a RC snubber in parallel with the piezo, no real difference. I tried a few different R values in parallel with the piezo, marginal improvement depending on the value. Adding a 220uF electrolytic cap to the 24V rail helped by ~ 2 - 5dBuV across all frequencies. I tried adjusting gate resistors, the larger the value, the worse the emissions.

I know that I can throw a PI filter on the input 24V supply to solve this issue, but with how horrible the emissions are, I feel like that is a bit of a "bandaid" fix. The fact that the larger gate resistor made this worse makes me think that even with the max deadband on the H-bridge driver, that there is a slight shoot-through issue, but I'm not sure. I also can't just put hundreds and hundreds uF of capacitance.

Any thoughts of what I could try to limit the emissions directly?

**EDIT:** I am directly measuring the input 24VDC using a 5uH LISN by [Tekbox](https://www.tekbox.com/product/tboh01-5uh-lisn-cispr-25/).

Comment: The performance of this circuit will be almost entirely determined by the parasitics of the passive components, and by the PCB layout. Without seeing PCB layout and actual part numbers used, it's a wild guess as to what may be wrong. *Any thoughts of what I could try to limit the emissions directly?* Decouple the piezo current loop from the rest of the circuit. Likely there are shared ground paths and such. But without seeing the layout - no idea what is wrong. The schematic is not adequate to pinpoint it.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Well I can't share the layout, but as a whole it won't affect conducted emission that significantly. It is a 4-layer PCB with very small loops however. "Decouple the piezo current loop from the rest of the circuit." Yes, that would the PI filter I mentioned.  I'd rather find the root cause instead.

Comment: Also, part numbers are visible for the ICs/FETs.

Comment: What happens when you substitute the piezo for a resistive load? What is the purpose of D1? What happens if you remove it?

Comment: @Kartman Yep tried it. Helps a little bit, few dBuV, nothing major. Also, it needs to be a pretty low resistance to help, so not practical

Comment: *[...] the layout, but as a whole it won't affect conducted emission that significantly.* So, you've figured it out already? How do you know it won't affect the emissions? I mean, if you know the answer, why ask? You don't need to share everything. Redo the layout of the part in question separately and post it. That way nobody will know what widget it's a part of. *I'd rather find the root cause instead* The root cause is that you have a very wideband current source, and you didn't constrain that current to flow where you want it to. The 1st source of such problems is layout.

Comment: Also, if you're sure that the layout is not a problem, you should be equipped to measure the currents flowing outside of where you'd intend, and show that they are small enough not to matter. If you claim that the layout is OK without measurements, and proper technique, to demonstrate that the layout is fine, then there's no point in claiming so. It's a wild guess at best.

Comment: At this point, the only way to answer your question is for someone to do a proper layout with those parts, show how it looks, and then you can figure out how close you are. That's perhaps asking for a lot, given that you already have your layout to look at...

Comment: I have the parts in question and could put a quick test bench together, but you'd need to share the circuit diagram of the LISN so that I could at least measure the same way you do. Also, where exactly in the circuit is the LISN connected? 24V/GND? Is the 5V/12V regulated locally? How does the higher level architecture of the power supply look in this product?

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Woah, lot to unpack. So I said it's likely not from the layout due to past experience. We do a lot of compliance testing and reviews. The low frequency of conducted emissions tends to make it not layout related unless it is horrible. Layout tends to affect higher frequencies for radiated more.

Comment: Good question on the LISN. I will edit the question. Also, here is a snippet of the layout: https://i.imgur.com/Q7GY3FS.png

The other reason I mentioned it likely not being the layout, is it's a 4-layer board, inner two are solid ground ref planes, bottom layer is solid 24VDC. It's about as perfectly setup for this drive as you can get, since the main current path is entirely on planes.

Comment: @KyleHunter Please put your layout image as part of the post and not a link (links can disappear). Your layout could be part of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your layout can use improvement.

- The FET bypass capacitors (C13, C15) are diving in to the ground
  plane. This means you have large glitch current (current spikes at the switching edges) running in your
  ground plane which can cause EMC issues.
- The positioning of your FETs create a large area current loop in conjunction with the FET bypass capacitors. Again, not optimal regarding EMC.

The following image is how I normally build H-bridge amplifiers for 10kW pulse systems. This is half of the H-bridge. Q1 is the upper FET, Q2 is the lower FET, C8 is the FET bypass capacitor. Note that the FET bypass capacitor is connected to Q1's drain and Q2's source directly on surface copper pours. This minimizes parasitic inductance. There are plane layers for the +24V and ground. This arrangement reduces glitch current from flowing in to the power planes and minimizes the loop area.

[image]

Consider using a ferrite bead on the 24V power line as part of a PI filter. This will probably improve the situation greatly as this will reduce the switching current glitches on the power line. You also need a few hundred microfarads (use multiple capacitors in parallel) on both sides of the PI filter. Use good quality capacitors rated for switching power supplies. You may need to de-Q the ferrite bead with a 10 to 20 ohm resistor across the ferrite bead. Ferrite beads can form an L-C circuit with the bypass capacitors and ring when hit with current spikes.

Check for cross conduction (hard to do on these types of amplifiers). You state emissions got worse when you increased the gate resistance which is a sign of cross-conduction. You would need to redesign the gate drive scheme (independent gate signals that you can adjust switching parameters) to ensure you don't have cross-conduction.

Consider inserting a tuning inductor in series with the output. If chosen right, the inductor will cancel out the capacitive reactance giving you a nearly resistive impedance. Driving a piezo transducer directly will give a current spike at the switching edges since the transducer looks like a capacitor (transducer is a complex impedance device that is frequency dependent).

Consider using a 100nF capacitor for one of your FET bypass capacitors. It will have better characteristics at higher frequencies.

Comment: Uh, unless I'm missing something here, your layout addresses a loop that only occurs on a shoot through condition... The standard loop is not between Q1 and Q2. It is instead between Q1 and Q4 or Q2 and Q3, depending on the state of the bridge. https://i.imgur.com/MUBzHhk.png show the two different loops.

Comment: I certainly can see room for improvement, and I certainly will adjust for the next revision, but I am very skeptical that it will help these low frequencies for conducted emissions. Looks like my original thought using a PI filter may be the only option